# Wordpress - How to detect an iPad tablet

Tags: wordpress, ipad, mobile, tablet, detect

So I have created a website in Wordpress to market a mobile app service that I provide.  Once a user signs up on the website, I want to detect the device that they are on and send them to the appropriate app store to install the app to make it a seamless transaction for them.  So far, I have been using a javascript library called MobileDetect that is based on a PHP MobileDetect project.  It is basically based on deciphering the useragent string to determine the device. This has been working fine for awhile, but recently with iOS 13, I can no longer detect an iPad because Apple has changed the useragent because they don't want mobile versions of websites popping up automatically on iPad Pro, they would prefer full desktop versions of the webite to appear.  So if a user signs up on a Android or an Amazon Fire device, I can still send them to the appropriate app store.  But I am not able to distinguish between whether they sign up on a computer or an iPad as MobileDetect now sees them as both the same.

How can I detect an iPad running iOS 13 so that I can send them to Apple's App Store to download my app after they sign up???

Comment: In general, browser sniffing is the wrong thing to do. Why not just take users to a page with both an Apple and Android link after they sign up, and let them click the right one?

Comment: This is definitely an option, one that I am seriously considering taking.  I would prefer to make it as fool proof and simple for the user as possible and just take a user where they are supposed to go.  Sadly, some clients do not even know what device they own ;) But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: There's a JS-based short-term solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019463/how-to-detect-device-name-in-safari-on-ios-13-while-it-doesnt-show-the-correct