# Redirect to App Store or Google Play based on device

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

We put together an app that needs to provide links to 3rd party apps for people to download. We are trying to link to a place to download the app. We want to make it so that when someone clicks the link they are forwarded either to the play store or the app store depending on what device they have. The problem is, the cross platform software used to make the app only allows us to put in a link with https. To compensate, created Html pages that redirect users to a place to download the the 3rd party app. The problem is that with an iPad, the Safari browser is detected and treated as if a PC instead of a tablet. We want to redirect people with iphones, ipads, or other mobile apple devices to the app store while users with android devices are sent to the play store. We are trying to avoid using any 3rd party dynamic link software and do this purely with code.

Here's what we tried so far. We set up an external html document and deep linked to this document from the app. Once the user gets to this redirecting document, its supposed to a) detect their device b) based on that device, redirect them to either the app store or the play store. However, with ipads it seems to be treated like a PC instead of a mobile device and does not redirect to the app store.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

      // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Windows Phone";
    }

    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }

    // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }

    return "unknown";
}</script>

<script>
function DetectAndServe(){
    let os = getMobileOperatingSystem();
    if (os == "Android") {
        window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs"; 
    } else if (os == "iOS") {
        window.location.href = "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-docs-sync-edit-share/id842842640";
    } else if (os == "Windows Phone") {
        window.location.href = "https://docs.google.com/";
    } else {
        window.location.href = "https://docs.google.com/";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="DetectAndServe()">
</body>
</html>
```

I suggested simply deleting the option for PC forcing the user to be redirected either to the app store or play store with no other options. My partner however said that in the future, with other projects, we may want to redirect users to an option for PC users and if this option were removed now, we may have to create additional files rather than the simplicity of one file per app to be redirected to. So we need another option to force ipads to be recognized as mobile devices. We also need for users to be  directed to a link that would open the app store / play store to download the 3rd party app, if they don't have it, or open the app if they do have it. It's most important however, to redirect users to the play store / app store. Does someone know a way to do this?

Comment: This question should give you the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019463/how-to-detect-device-name-in-safari-on-ios-13-while-it-doesnt-show-the-correct

Comment: This does seem to be what I'm looking for, but how would you put that into a conditional "if" statement like what I have above. I'm very new to Javascript. the code @Weetz on that forum shows how to detect an ipad, but it doesn't show me how to work it into the conditions I posted above. Here's what I'm trying. Is this correct? 

'    if ((/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform) ||
  (navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1)) &&
  !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }'